# simulate mousedown event on input of type range at a previse (x, y) point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

In react, I need to be able to simulate a mousedown event on a range slider, i.e. an input element of type "range".

Particularly, the simulated click should be on the thumb of the slider.

But a solution that can simulate a click at a precise (x, y) value is also welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: We could give you a suggestion, but it would be much more helpful and will probably yield a better answer if you would provide the relevant part of your React code where you need to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.click()` to simulate a click on a specific element.

An example can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

And it may be possible to click from a certain x and y coordinate. I can't give code, because I don't have enough information from you, but this link could help you out.

https://thewebdev.info/2021/05/23/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript/